# Insert geometry on spatialite always insert null C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, spatialite

I'm trying to insert a geometry (POINT, LINE, POLYGON) into a table in a sqlite  DB (spatialite), all the code run OK but at time to see the rows, the column of geometry always is NULL.

The info in the DB after INSERT.
[image]

How it should be: 
[image]

The result of string SQL is OK, I'm using

```
INSERT INTO Table1( Codigo, Nombre, Geometry) VALUES('1','Andalucia',GeomFromText('POLYGON((-75.8396284742612 8.39962954808519, ..., -75.8396284742612 8.39962954808519))', 4326));

INSERT INTO Table2( Codigo, Nombre, Geometry) VALUES('1','Andalucia',GeomFromText('POINT(-75.8361480385065 8.40883548152381)', 4326));
```

This is my code on C#:

```
public SQLiteConnection create_Open_SpatilaDB(string dbName)
{
    try
    {
        dbName += DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssff") + ".sqlite";

        string ruta = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Uploads/" + dbName);

        string strConexion = "Data Source=" + ruta + ";Version=3;";

        SQLiteConnection conexion = null;

        if (!File.Exists(ruta))
        {
            // create the connection
            conexion = new SQLiteConnection(strConexion);

            //Abrir la conexión
            conexion.Open();

            //Load the lib
            conexion.EnableExtensions(true);
            conexion.LoadExtension("libspatialite-2.dll");                    

            //Create tables
            string SQL = "CREATE TABLE AppVersion ("
                        + " versionCode INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                        + " state INTEGER NOT NULL);";

            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, conexion);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SQL = "CREATE TABLE Table1 ("                        
                + " Codigo TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                + " Nombre TEXT,"
                + " Geometry POLYGON);";

            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, conexion);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SQL = "CREATE TABLE Table2("
                    + " Codigo TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + " Nombre TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + " Geometry POIN);";

            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, conexion);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            .
            .
            .
        }
        else
        {
            conexion = new SQLiteConnection(strConexion);
            conexion.Open();
            conexion.EnableExtensions(true);
            conexion.LoadExtension("libspatialite-2.dll");
        }

        return conexion;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

And here i'm inserting the info:

```
public void insertInfo(SQLiteConnection conexion)
{
    try
    {
        string SQL = "BEGIN";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, conexion);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Insert info table1        
        List<Table1> list = getInfoTable1();

        foreach (Table1 item in list)
        {
            SQL = "INSERT INTO Table1("
                    + " Codigo,"
                    + " Nombre,"
                    + " Geometry) VALUES("
                    + "'" + item.Codigo + "',"
                    + "'" + item.Nombre + "',"
                    + "GeomFromText(" + item.geom + "));";

            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, conexion);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        //Insert info table1        
        List<Table2> list = getInfoTable2();

        foreach (Table2 item in list)
        {
            SQL = "INSERT INTO Table2("
                    + " Codigo,"
                    + " Nombre,"
                    + " Geometry) VALUES("
                    + "'" + item.Codigo + "',"
                    + "'" + item.Nombre + "',"
                    + "GeomFromText(" + item.geom + "));";

            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, conexion);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        .
        .
        .
        SQL = "COMMIT";
        cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, conexion);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to mark the column of your table as the geometry column; otherwise it is not recognized as the geometry column.

For this you should use the RecoverGeometryColumn-Function in order to transform you normal column to a geometry column.
Otherwise you could also use the AddGeometryColumn-Function
Have a look on this link: 
https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html

Furthermore if you really want to use C# you should consider Spatialite > 4.2.0 with the System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET provider for SQLite. 
Maybe you can have a look in this discussion here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/u2QZpQL_6ek